# wsHttpsBinding Vs wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, wcf-wshttpbinding

I have often come across *wsHttpBinding* when writing code for WCF projects. However, I have never used *wsHttp**s**Binding*.

**Question**: Does *wsHttp**s**Binding* even exist in WCF or its a custom binding? If it exists, then why would a developer use *wsHttp**s**Binding* rather than *wsHttpBinding*?

Answer (score 1):

WsHttpBinding also supports interoperability. With this binding, the SOAP message is, by default, encrypted. It supports HTTP and HTTPS. In terms of encoding, it provides support for Text as well as MTOM encoding methods. It supports WS-* standards like WS-Addressing, WS-Security and WS-ReliableMessaging. By default, reliable sessions are disabled because it can cause a bit of performance overhead.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431291/WCF-Services-Choosing-the-appropriate-WCF-binding